# Example Problem from "Lecture Notes on Elementary Topology and Differential Geometry" (Singer/Thorpe)

Tags: general-topology, product-space

The following is an example problem from the above-mentioned text:

"Let $J^+$ = [n, n is a positive integer] and let $I_n = [0, 1/n]$. Then $P = (\pi_{n \; \in \; J^+}, I_n)$ is a topological space in the product topology. We introduce a metric on the point set of $P$ as follows..."

My question is the following:

What product space corresponds to the product topology mentioned above?

EDIT: The notation $(\pi_{n \; \in \; J^+}, I_n)
$ seems to suggest that said product topology corresponds to the set $I_n$. If this is the case, how can $I_n$ be treated as a product space?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does $\pi_{n \in J^+}$ mean?

Comment: @ mvpq I would assume that said notation represents the aforementioned "product topology", though the text never states as such explicitly...

Comment: I think you mean $\prod$ instead of $\pi$, i.e. the symbol for product. Then $P=\prod_{n\in J^+}I_n$ is the product of the sets $I_n$ as $n$ ranges over the positive integers.

Comment: @ mvpq That makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is *possible* (but notationally very weird) that what is being provided is a collection of canonical projections and their image spaces.  Starting from that guess, your product space is $J^+$-indexed sequences, where the $n^\text{th}$ element of the sequence is an element of $I_n$.

A slight reduction in notational weirdness would be 
$$( (\pi_n, I_n))_{n \in J^+}  \text{,}  $$
which more clearly indicates a sequence indexed by $J^+$together with canonical projection - images space pairs.  In either case, this mode of specification and the one in the Question are very category theoretic in that the specification provides the data necessary to construct the commutative diagram for the [universal property of a product space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology#Properties).

As others have written in comments, "$  P = \prod_{n \in J^+} I_n  $
with element-wise canonical projections" would be a far less weird way to specify this space.

Comment: @ Eric Towers If I am reading your answer correctly, you are saying that $\pi_n$ represents the projection map rather than the product topology on the indexed set $I_n$, right?

Comment: Yes.  $\pi_n$ is projection to the $n$-th factor in the product.

Comment: @ Eric Towers Alright, thanks. I hate to bother you further with notational issues but in general, it seems that $\Pi_{w \in W} S_w$ represents the product of sets $S_w$ indexed by some set $W$. However, in my text here, I have seen the notation $\pi_{w \in W} S_w$ used. Does this indicate the product of sets or does it mean something else, such as the projection maps? My text, unfortunately, did not elaborate on this notation.

Comment: @JG123 : Page 4 of your [text](http://webmath2.unito.it/paginepersonali/sergio.console/Dispense/Singer%20Thorpe%20Topolog%23682C8.pdf) "*Definition*.  Let $\{S_w\}_{w \in W}$ be indexed by $W$.  The *product* of the sets $\{S_w\}_{w \in W}$ is the set $$\prod_{w \in W} S = [f:W \rightarrow \bigcup_{w \in W} S_w; f(w) \in S_w \text{ for all } w \in W]  \text{."}$$  Note that they are *not* using $\pi$; they are using $\prod$. Inline, the underset specification is made a subscript: $\prod_{w \in W}$

Comment: @JG123 : Page 14 of your text has uses of both $\pi$ and $\prod$.  There, $\prod$ is an indexed Cartesian product and the $\pi_j$ are projection maps in Example 1.

Comment: @ Eric Towers I see. Thank you!